# Standard Normal Distribution and sum of mean and deviation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

I am studying for the exam on Probability and I have some questions about Standard Normal Distribution.

In particular I am solving an exercise and I don't know if I am solving it correctly.

The exercise is this:

There is a machine that fills jars to a weight that is normally distributed with mean 400g and a standard deviation 4g.

a) What is the probability that a jar will be at least 410g?

b) What is the probability that 2 jars will be at least 822g?

I solved like this:

a) $Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} = \frac{410 - 400}{4} = \frac{10}{4} = 2.5$
Now, looking at the Distribution Table, I see that

$Pr[X>410] = 1 - 0.9938 = 0.0062$

b) $Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} = \frac{822 - 800}{8} = \frac{11}{4} = 2.75$

Now, looking at the Distribution Table, I see that

$Pr[X>822] = 1 - 0.9970 = 0.003$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: If the probability distributions of the two jars are independent, then you add variances, not standard deviations.  Therefore the standard deviation for the sum of two jars is $\sqrt{2}(\sigma )=5.65685424949238$, not $8$.

Comment: Excuse me @herbsteinberg, can you please show me how do you calculate this 5.65685424949238? Thanks

Comment: $4\sqrt{2}$. using a calculator.

Comment: @herbsteinberg but why do you have these data? 4 is the standard deviation, and 2 is what?

Comment: When adding two independent random variables, the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances $=2\sigma^2$ in this case, so the stand deviation for the sum $=\sqrt{2}\sigma$.